# Regexp - How to match all words except strict ones?

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, regex-negation, codeigniter-routing

I'm trying to find a regexp that exclude specific word but not words containing it.

For example if we exclude the word "home"

```
home --> NOT OK
homefree -> OK
freehome -> OK
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend taking a look at [**Rexegg — Word Boundaries**](http://rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary).

If you want to match lines not containing "home" itself, you can do:

```
preg_match_all('/^(?!.*\bhome\b).*$/im', $str, $matches);
```

If you want to match the words alone:

```
preg_match_all('/\b(?!home\b)\w+/i', $str, $matches);
```